# Firebase remoteMessage getData proper NullPointer handling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some problem with handling NullPointer exception from remoteMessage.

I've tried to do simple check:

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

if(data != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.getData().get("lat"));
        Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.getData().get("lng"));
    }
```

I also tried harder:

```
  if(remoteMessage.getData().get("lat") != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.getData().get("lat"));
    }
```

But it always crashes with NullPointer:

```
05-29 10:22:33.112 21028-24256/com.coderspeak.smog_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-12-thread-1
                                                                     Process: com.coderspeak.smog_app, PID: 21028
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                         at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
                                                                         at com.coderspeak.smog_app.services.fcm.AppFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(AppFirebaseMessagingService.java:50)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzl(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzJ(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
```

How can i do the proper check for this?

Comment: Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.getData().get("lat")+"");

Comment: Could you try printing the whole `data`? Like so, `Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
if (remoteMessage != null &&
    remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
    String yourMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("lat"));

    if (yourMessage != null) {
         Log.d(TAG, yourMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: remoteMessage.getData().get("lat") always gives a crash

Comment: The type returned by the getData() method call is a Map instance or is a custom type? Maybe the NPE occurs inside the get() method.